# How to add vertical rectangle to subplots

Tags: python, plotly

I want to make vertical rectangles that cover a time period in my subplot using add_vrect function, but the code below produced nothing. I didn't know which part is incorrect. Please help me!

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
from datetime import timedelta
import pandas as pd 


x=[ "2015-02-01", "2015-02-02",  "2015-02-03", "2015-02-04", "2015-02-05",
    "2015-02-06", "2015-02-07", "2015-02-08", "2015-02-09", "2015-02-10",
    "2015-02-11", "2015-02-12", "2015-02-13", "2015-02-14", "2015-02-15",
    "2015-02-16", "2015-02-17", "2015-02-18", "2015-02-19", "2015-02-20",
    "2015-02-21", "2015-02-22", "2015-02-23", "2015-02-24", "2015-02-25",
    "2015-02-26", "2015-02-27", "2015-02-28"]

y=[]
for i in x:
    i=pd.to_datetime(i)
    j=i+timedelta(days=14)
    y.append(j)

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1)
  
for i in range(len(x)):
    fig.add_vrect(x0=x[i], x1=y[i], fillcolor='powderblue', opacity=0.15,
                line_width=0, row=2, col=1)

fig.show()
```

Comment: Do you have an example of the output you expect? And what is the reason for using subplots? Do you want to draw something like a Gantt chart?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of the reason for this (will update the answer if I figure it out), but it seems that the units of timestamps for the axes aren't recognized until you add a trace of some sort which is why you are probably getting this plot:

[image]

But if you plot a random point from your data (with a timestamp unit) using `go.Scatter` and make it invisible by setting the `opacity=0`, then the vertical rectangle annotations show up.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
from datetime import timedelta
import pandas as pd 


x=[ "2015-02-01", "2015-02-02",  "2015-02-03", "2015-02-04", "2015-02-05",
    "2015-02-06", "2015-02-07", "2015-02-08", "2015-02-09", "2015-02-10",
    "2015-02-11", "2015-02-12", "2015-02-13", "2015-02-14", "2015-02-15",
    "2015-02-16", "2015-02-17", "2015-02-18", "2015-02-19", "2015-02-20",
    "2015-02-21", "2015-02-22", "2015-02-23", "2015-02-24", "2015-02-25",
    "2015-02-26", "2015-02-27", "2015-02-28"]

y=[]
for i in x:
    i=pd.to_datetime(i)
    j=i+timedelta(days=14)
    y.append(j)

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[x[0]],y=[y[0]],mode='markers',opacity=0), row=2,col=1)

for i in range(len(x)):
    fig.add_vrect(x0=x[i], x1=y[i], fillcolor='powderblue', opacity=0.15,
                line_width=0, row=2, col=1)
fig.show()
```

[image]